# Solve $|x^2-5|\geq 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> $$|x^2-5|\geq 4$$

$|x^2-5|\geq 4\Rightarrow$ $x^2-5\geq 4 $ or $x^2-5\leq -4$

Case:  $x^2-5\geq 4\Rightarrow x^2-9\geq0\Rightarrow (x-3)(x+3)\geq 0$ so the answer is $x\geq 3$ or $x\leq -3$

case: $x^2-5\leq -4\Rightarrow x^2-1\leq 0 \Rightarrow (x-1)(x+1)\leq 0$ so the answer is $-1\leq x \leq 1$

Now I need to take both as they both need to fulfil the inequality (intersection of both answers) so the answer should be an empty set?

Comment: No, your use of the word "or" in the first line shows that either condition suffices, so the solution set is the *union* of the solution sets for the two cases.

Answer (score 3):

Not at all.. The answer will be the **union** of the two sets and **not** their **intersection**.

Remember when you say $|x^2-5|\ge 4\implies x^2-5\ge 4\ \textbf{OR}\ x^2-5\le -4$ This  OR results in a union not intersection.

Comment: got confuse with the case of $ |f(x)|\leq a$ in this case it is the intersection, right?

Comment: Yes, it is. You're not the only one to be confused. I have programmed like this before now: "`If x is less than -4 and x is more than 4 then`..." and then wondered why nothing was working!!!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving this:

$$\left|x^2-5\right|\ge 4\iff \left(x^2-5\right)^2\ge 4^2$$

$$\iff \left(x^2-9\right)\left(x^2-1\right)\ge 0$$

$$\iff x^2\in(-\infty;1]\cup[9;+\infty)$$

$$\iff x^2\in[0;1]\cup [9;+\infty)$$

$$\iff x\in(-\infty;-3]\cup[-1;1]\cup[3;+\infty)$$